# Adding Shared Contact to be a member of a Google Group is not working

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to add Shared Contact to be a member of a Google Group, but it is giving below error

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Invalid Input: memberKey [400]
Errors [
    Message[Invalid Input: memberKey] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]
]
```

Input:

```
groupKey : grp_tw_dist01_display@dev.groupondev.com 
memberKey: 2809da4408a97397
role: MEMBER
Api: PUT https: //www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey/members/memberKey
```

Comment: Please explain how did you shared the contact? Did you follow one of the steps here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/1JQaeQrJQ_g or did you use https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/

Comment: I have used second approach.